# Ubuntu 15.04 installation gets stuck at loading screen

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

When I boot from the USB stick with Ubuntu 15.04 on it, I'm offered with the choice of trying Ubuntu or installing it directly. Neither of those work as in I don't get past the loading screen. Before that, there are some messages with one of the first ones being `ACPI PCC probe failed` but the internet™ says, it's fine. Also I get reoccurring errors like these (seems to be related to my graphics card):

```
[   50435508] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:03:00.0] SCHED_ERROR [ UNK06  ]
```

I’m completely lost and don’t know where to start now. Any help is deeply appreciated. How can I install Ubuntu on its own partition?

**The Setup**

- **Operating system:** Windows 8.1 (64-bit) that was pre-installed on an Acer laptop (UEFI)
- **Graphics card:** Nvidia GeForce GTX 850M
- **Boot Mode:** EFI / **Partition style:** GPT ([Identifying which boot mode the OS uses](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html))
- Fast Startup and Secure Boot are disabled
- There is free space on my hard drive which is not yet partitioned
- Windows 8.1 installation disk in case I need to repair something
- <s>Bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 15.04 created by [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) (MD5 Checksum of the iso file was verified)</s>
- Ubuntu installation medium on USB stick created with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: First, I've seen a lot of problem reports about the tool you used to create the Ubuntu installer. I suspect that it creates images that are unbootable in EFI mode. I'd try something else, like [Rufus.](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) Second, it's imperative that you install both OSes in the same mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI). To do that, you must know the Windows boot mode. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) of mine for information on how to do that.

Comment: @RodSmith I will try Rufus. Also, I added the information about the boot mode to the question. It's EFI.

Comment: @RodSmith Trying again with a stick being preparred with Rufus did not change the results. I'm still stuck in the loading screen.

Comment: Just saying again, ACPI PCC probe failed isn't even anything and it is pretty common, i even get it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem.
Disabling Fast Boot AND CSM got me throught the to the installation. 
Without Fast Boot I got to the loading screen, but then it got stuck. I read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_UEFI_mode) and as far as I understand, CSM allows non-UEFI installations. Since I have Windows 10 already installed and booting fro UEFI and want a dual boot, I tried disabling CSM et voilà, I am installing ubuntu 15.10 on my ASUS N552VX as we speak.

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem, both "Try Ubuntu before installing" and "Install Ubuntu" were getting stuck at the loading screen.

I fixed it by following these steps :

1. When the grub screen comes up, highlight "Install Ubuntu" and press <kbd>e</kbd> on the keyboard.
2. A command line opens, in the second line, navigate to the end and type the following after the two hyphens `nouveau modeset=0`
3. Hit <kbd>F10</kbd>, it reboots and will work normally.